# Cannot install php 8.0 on ubuntu, E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-20.04, php-8

I am trying to install LEMP on vultr's Ubuntu 22.04 server.
I can install Nginx `sudo apt install -y nginx` - no problem.

But when I try to install php8.0 by running these commands

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

I keep getting error `The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.`

Here is what I get after running the `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` command

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
PPA publishes dbgsym, you may need to include 'main/debug' component
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.x and most requested extensions are included. Only Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.

Debian oldstable and stable packages are provided as well: https://deb.sury.org/#debian-dpa

You can get more information about the packages at https://deb.sury.org

IMPORTANT: The <foo>-backports is now required on older Ubuntu releases.

BUGS&FEATURES: This PPA now has a issue tracker:
https://deb.sury.org/#bug-reporting

CAVEATS:
1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
3. If you are using nginx, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
   or ppa:ondrej/nginx

PLEASE READ: If you like my work and want to give me a little motivation, please consider donating regularly: https://donate.sury.org/

WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php.gpg with fingerprint 14AA40EC0831756756D7F66C4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
Get:1 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/canonical-kernel-team/unstable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:6 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1,408 kB]
Ign:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:8 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [14.1 MB]
Err:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 443]
Get:10 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en [5,645 kB]
Get:11 http://us.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [286 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any thoughts / suggestions why this is happening and what should I do differently?

Comment: I would imagine that your issue is the result of 22.04 not being released yet. If you look [here](https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/) you'll see there is no jammy subdir.

Comment: Hmm.... @AlexHowansky, I wonder why there is tutorial on vultr (and more on web) on how to install php8+ on ubuntu 2204  https://www.vultr.com/es/docs/installing-configuring-and-securing-php-8-1-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: 22.04 already comes with 8.1 natively, you don't need the Ondrej PPA for it.

Comment: Alex Howansky, what would be your suggestion on how to install php8.0 on 22.04?

Comment: Wait until 22.04 is actually released. Or use 22.10. Or compile from source. Or use 8.1.

Comment: @AlexHowansky My Ubuntu Server is version 22.0.4.1 LTS and I still have this issue as well ?

Comment: You must see the Get while running the command "add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php" on your terminal if you are seeing Ignore or Hit, there is a problem with connection to those servers.

Answer (score 8):

It is the issue of the result of 22.10 not being released yet ppa:ondrej/php repository. It will fix it by ppa:ondrej/php, but I have found a solution for this,i don't think it is the best solution,

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list
```

then add this line and save it

```
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ jammy main
#deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/kinetic main
```

then try to install it again

**PHP 7.2**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-fpm
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml php7.2-gd php7.2-curl
```

**PHP 8.0**

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0 php8.0-fpm
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring php8.0-xml php8.0-gd php8.0-curl
```

for this answer i have helped these [link_01](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438143/can-install-php7-4-on-ubuntu-22-10) [link_02](https://techvblogs.com/blog/install-multiple-php-versions-on-ubuntu-22-04)

now successfully installed PHP, so you can switch easily the PHP version,

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

select the version for enter the number, now check the PHP version

```
php -v
```

Comment: Thanks @Chinthaka. Worked perfectly. Just installed PHP 8.2.4 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: But if you are using Ubuntu 22.04 its not a problem,  only you need to install php 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && sudo apt update and after install php(you want version)

Comment: after adding the repository line you need to run sudo apt update to install the packages